# Cannot access Django server on EC2 instance

Tags: python, django, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance.  Installed Python 3.4 on it and then installed Django 1.10.6 on it.  I was trying to develop my first django application

I started django server.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I could not access at http://n.n.n.n:8000. 
I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

I went back to the EC2 instance and added the protocol/port to the security group.  This is how it looks after I add the port/proptocol

```
Custom TCP Rule  TCP  8000  0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule  TCP  8000  ::/0
```

It did not work. I even added a rule to allow all traffic from anywhere. It still did not work.

However, if I  start django server the following way

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I get the following error:

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'n.n.n.n:8000'. You may need to add 'n.n.n.n' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

If tried adding the IP to ProjectName/settings.py,

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['n.n.n.n'] #Make sure your host IP is a string
```

I get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

I can ping the IP.  I can ssh (there is rule to allow ssh). Does not  look like there is a firewall.

```
$ sudo service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
```

Why am I not able access http/django server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I must not have started the server right, when I added the host to the ProjectName/settings.py file.  I tried again, and this time it worked.

So looks like

django server started on EC2 instances with the following

```
python manage.py runserver
```

may not be accessible from other machines.

django server started with the following

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

would be accessible from the Internet provided the IP address of the host machine is added to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in the ProjectName/settings.py file

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['n.n.n.n'] #Make sure your host IP is a string
```

This is all in addition to the entries in the security group

Comment: Hi @user2125853, when you say add host IP to the ALLOWED_HOSTS, is it the IP of the ec2 instance or IP of the machine you are trying to access Django from?

Answer (score 0):

The IP to the allowed hosts means the IP of the devices which you want to access Django from.